# Include CSS and JS library into vue spa component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

so i am working on vue spa project and want to integrate ckeditor5 into it. so i just npm install ckeditor5 vue version from [here](https://github.com/igorxut/vue-ckeditor5) and everything works fine by following instalation guide on the github site.

but after using it, i realize that i need to make custom build from there and thats mean i need to fork the build and clone it and do something on it and then npm build and then add it into my project

well the problem is i don't know how to include those css and js to my vue spa component (i only need it on specific component so i don't find any benefit by putting it avaiable on global by just adding css and js file to the html)

so how to add it on the specific component on vue spa?

Comment: Can you share your error message and the component you're trying to import these in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried this myself but as for the css this should work:

```
<style lang="css" src="path/to/some.css" scoped>
```

Or

```
<style lang="scss" src="path/to/some.scss" scoped>
```

You can add as much css files (style tags) as needed on your vue template... also, if you don't need this css to be scoped (just available in the component, not in children or parent components) just remove the scoped attribute.

And for the JS, you may load it with: `require('path/to/some.js');`

or if you need to assign it to something in the window object: `window.numeral = require('numeral');`... that's an example using the numeral library...